# Unable to identify a muscle of the anterior thorax

Tags: physiology, human-anatomy

I was watching an [YouTube Anatomy Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZJNZCyqAw) which goes over the major muscles of the anterior superficial thorax. There is a structure present throughout the video which goes unmentioned, and I can't seem to identify.

[image]

It is shown as a pair of structures, each running from the manubrium to the xiphisternal junction along the lateral margin of the anterior sternum, perhaps with a second head attaching to the costal cartilage.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but for the life of me I can't think of what that could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the [sternalis muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sternalis_muscle). The reason it is not mentioned may because it is not present in all individuals, and is therefore relatively poorly characterised.

The image is from `An Atlas of anatomy by regions` by John Charles Boileau Grant.

[image]

Another image of the muscle can be found in `Pocket Atlas of Human Anatomy` by Thieme:

[image]
[image]